# Subset dataframe based on list objects

Tags: r, regex, subset

I have a dataframe with speech data in column `Turn`:

```
test <- data.frame(
  Turn = c("Hi. I'm you an' you are me cos",
          "she'd've been so happy cos with all this stuff goin' on",
          "but we're in this together, because y' know things happens",
          "so you can't, cos well, ah because you know why!",
          "not now because it's too late!"), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

I want to subset the dataframe on those rows in which there are **at least four words prior to `cos` and/or `because`**. To this end I compute the indices of `cos`and `because` in their `Turn`:

```
test$Index <- sapply(strsplit(test$Turn, " "), function(x) which(x == 'cos'|x == 'because'))
test
                                                        Turn Index
1                             Hi. I'm you an' you are me cos     8
2    she'd've been so happy cos with all this stuff goin' on     5
3 but we're in this together, because y' know things happens     6
4           so you can't, cos well, ah because you know why!  4, 7
5                             not now because it's too late!     3
```

In one row there is more than one index. That's why my attempt at subsetting like this fails:

```
test[test$Index >= 5,]
Error in `[.data.frame`(test, test$Index >= 5, ) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

How can I subset `test` by disregarding the second listed `Index` value?

Expected result:

```
test
                                                        Turn Index
1                             Hi. I'm you an' you are me cos     8
2    she'd've been so happy cos with all this stuff goin' on     5
3 but we're in this together, because y' know things happens     6
```

I'd be grateful for any answer, including one that that does not use the detour via the indices but uses a `regex` pattern for the subsetting procedure.

**EDIT**:

The solution, within the `sapply` paradigm, is really quite simple by selecting just the first value of the listed objects:

```
sapply(test$Index, function(x) x[1])
[1] 4 5 6 4 3
```

Comment: It is not clear what you consider a word. Why is the expected output just those three strings?

Comment: Why does line 4 not match? There are 6 words before `because`?

Comment: Line 4 does not match because there is `cos` already in position 4.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I consider a word anything separated by whitespace, i.e., `Hi.` counts as one word just as `she'd've`counts as one word.

Comment: Do I understand it right that if `cos` or `because` appear as the first, second, third or fourth word in the string you would like to skip/omit/filter out the string?

Comment: Absolutely right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will give you an idea:

```r
test <- data.frame(
  Turn = c("Hi. I'm you an' you are me cos",
          "she'd've been so happy cos with all this stuff goin' on",
          "but we're in this together, because y' know things happens",
          "so you can't, cos well, ah because you know why!",
          "not now because it's too late!"), stringsAsFactors = F)
rx <- "^\\s*(?:\\S+\\s+){0,3}(?:cos|because)\\b.*(*SKIP)(*F)|(?:\\S+[\\s,]+){4}\\b(cos|because)\\b"
Turn <- test[grepl(rx, test$Turn, perl=TRUE),]
split <- strsplit(Turn, "\\b(cos|because)\\b")
Index <- sapply(split, function(x) lengths(strsplit(trimws(x[[1]]), "\\s+"))+1)
test <- data.frame(Turn, Index, stringsAsFactors = F)
test
```

Output:

```r
                                                       Turn Index
1                             Hi. I'm you an' you are me cos     8
2    she'd've been so happy cos with all this stuff goin' on     5
3 but we're in this together, because y' know things happens     6
```

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/7rE341) and the [main regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0e8hbK/4).

**Regex details**:

- `^\s*(?:\S+\s+){0,3}(?:cos|because)\b.*(*SKIP)(*F)` - match start of stirng, then zero to three words and then `cos` or `because` as a whole word and the rest of the string and then skip the match
- `|` - or
- `(?:\S+[\s,]+){4}\b(cos|because)\b` - match `cos` or `because` prepended with four words.

Comment: The solution is really this: `Turn <- test[grepl(rx, test$Turn, perl=TRUE),]`. Why do I need the remainder of the code (`split <- strsplit(Turn, "\\b(cos|because)\\b")
Index <- sapply(split, function(x) lengths(strsplit(trimws(x[[1]]), "\\s+"))+1)
test <- data.frame(Turn, Index, stringsAsFactors = F)`)?

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann Well, you showed the expected output, I tried to follow.

Answer (score 1):

A solution based in the tidyverse could look as follows.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)

test %>%
  mutate(index = map(str_split(Turn, ' '), 
                     ~ str_which(., 'cos|because')[1])) %>%
  filter(index >= 5)

#                                                         Turn index
# 1                             Hi. I'm you an' you are me cos     8
# 2    she'd've been so happy cos with all this stuff goin' on     5
# 3 but we're in this together, because y' know things happens     6
```

Comment: I get this error: `Error: Problem with 'mutate()' input 'Index'.
x could not find function "map"
ℹ Input 'Index' is `map(str_split(Turn, " "), ~str_which(., "cos|because")[1])`.
Run 'rlang::last_error()' to see where the error occurred.`

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann: Error message makes sense since ```library(purrr)``` was missing from my post. It has now been added.